# Unclear on LAST_VALUE - Preceding

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table that looks like this,

```
Date                   Value
01/01/2010 03:59:00     324.44
01/02/2010 09:31:00     NULL
01/02/2010 09:32:00     NULL
.
.
.
01/02/2010 11:42:00     NULL
```

I want the first valid value to appear in all following rows. This is what I did,

```
select date, 
   nvl(value, LAST_VALUE(value IGNORE NULLS) over (order by value RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) value
from
    table
```

This shows no difference at all, but if I say `RANGE BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` it copies the data to all the rows. I'm not clear why this is happening. Can anyone explain if I'm misunderstanding how to use preceding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytic functions still work on sets of data.  They do not process one row at a time, you would need PL/SQL or MODEL to do that.  `PRECEDING` refers to the last X rows, but before the analytic function has been applied.

These problems can be confusing in SQL because you have to build the logic into defining the set, instead of trying to pass data from one row to another.  That's why I used `CASE` with `LAST_VALUE` in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8273101/409172).

---

**Edit:**

I've added a simple data set so we can all run the exact same query.  `VALUE1` seems to work to me, am I missing something?  Part of the problem with `VALUE2` is that the analytic ORDER BY uses VALUE, instead of the date.

```
select id, the_date, value
    ,last_value(value ignore nulls) over
        (partition by id order by the_date) value1
    ,nvl(value, LAST_VALUE(value IGNORE NULLS) over
        (order by value RANGE BETWEEN 1 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)) value2
from
(
    select 1 id, date '2011-01-01' the_date, 100  value from dual union all
    select 1 id, date '2011-01-02' the_date, null value from dual union all
    select 1 id, date '2011-01-03' the_date, null value from dual union all
    select 1 id, date '2011-01-04' the_date, null value from dual union all
    select 1 id, date '2011-01-05' the_date, 200  value from dual
)
order by the_date;
```

Results:

```
ID  THE_DATE    VALUE   VALUE1  VALUE2
1   1/1/2011    100     100     100
1   1/2/2011            100     
1   1/3/2011            100     
1   1/4/2011            100     
1   1/5/2011    200     200     200
```

Comment: I dont expect it to work one row at a time, which is why I'm trying to make it pick the first non-null value above itself. But I see thats not happening.

Comment: Ok. I was using `nvl(value, last_value(value ignore nulls) over
        (partition by id order by the_date) value1`. This works. Thanks

Comment: You may want to delete your previous question, as these two questions have kinda merged together.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to copy one row at time because i had done that using java Logic and Sql query

```
            Statement sta;
            ResultSet rs,rslast;

            try{
```

//Connection creation code and "con" is an object of Connection Class so don't confuse about that.

```
    sta = con.createStatement();

    rs=sta.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLE NAME");
    rslast=sta.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME WHERE ID = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM TABLENAME)");
    rslast.next();
    String digit  =rslast.getString("ID");

    System.out.print("ID"+rslast.getString("ID")); // it gives ID of the Last Record.
```

Instead using this method u can also use ORDER by Date in Descending order.

Now i hope u make logic that only insert Last record.